# Is the audio average speaking rate or slower than normal?

Tags: listening

Recently i am listening to the bbc learning material such as below (uploaded on my dropbox and shared with all)
[sample audio](https://www.dropbox.com/s/36vux0ln9133szz/sample.mp3?dl=0)
Would you please tell me that the audio is average speaking rate or slower than normal?

Comment: The speech is normal, though she does emphasise the pauses more than most people would in ordinary conversation.

Comment: This speech sounds like that of a trained and experienced BBC radio broadcaster. Normal speaking rate, very clear enunciation, well defined pauses.

Comment: 'Good microphone technique' in fact.

Comment: "normal" speaking rate depends very much on where you are. I'm from New York, and I'm told that we speak quickly here. When I visit the southern US, I get frustrated with how slowly people speak, but I'm constantly told that I can't be understood because I speak too quickly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To my ears, as a native British English speaker, this speech is perfectly normal speed for the format. The pausing between sentences may be longer than some media formats, but it seems right for the material.

The BBC has many and varied platforms. You would find that presenters speak much faster on certain BBC radio stations, but on others this would not be out of place. As you say, this is specifically learning material. The speaker is reading from a script, and almost certainly making more careful and deliberate pausing because of the purpose of the material, but the pace is quite normal.